# Why IE executes javascript slower than Mozilla FF

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Why IE executes javascript slower than Mozilla FF? Even when i user pagemethods to get the data from web server. IE takes more time than Mozilla FF. Is there any way i can execute my asp.net project faster in IE same as FF?

Comment: Call up the IE dev team and tell them to make their next version as fast as Firefox.

Comment: Are you talking about JavaScript performance or AJAX performance? If its AJAX then are you experiencing a difference in network latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends how you write your javascsript. Both browsers have their strengths and weaknesses, although test with IE9, the javascript is far superior to previous versions. However I've seen many cases in prior versions where firefox outperformed IE - thats just how it is in some cases. Funny though that IE outperformed Google's Chrome browser (at least on one particular test anyways) on youtube performance : )

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the latency occurs from the JS or from the IE application itself by utilising YSlow (for IE) and measuring it against the results you garner from FireBug(FF).

Give it a go and post your results up here for further discussion. Might be your code, might just be that Internet Exploder is really really poo. My guess, the latter.